# Getting a file to Samsung Galaxy Tab from my Laptop without Android?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab, installation

I am trying to install new Android OS to Samsung Galaxy Tab but it does not have a Memory-card -slot and it does not have any OS currently. I need to somehow get the OS -file to the Samsung Galaxy Tab from my laptop, how can I do it?

**ttyACM3 -description with ls**

```
# ls -al /dev/ttyACM3 
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 3 Oct 27 14:06 /dev/ttyACM3
```

**Dmesg**

```
 [538846.011011] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[539228.371156] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 67 using ehci_hcd
[539228.387241] hub 2-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[539228.882058] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 68 using ehci_hcd
[539228.990676] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[539228.990685] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[539228.990691] usb 2-1.2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[539228.990696] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[539228.990700] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[539228.995453] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[539228.995729] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[539820.734285] thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
[539820.734288] thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6040
[539820.734290] thinkpad_acpi: please report the conditions when this event happened to ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
[539820.734655] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
```

**usb-devices**

```
:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 69 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04e8 ProdID=6860 Rev=04.00
S:  Manufacturer=SAMSUNG
S:  Product=SAMSUNG_Android
S:  SerialNumber=4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=96mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=42 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

I can see that my laptop can detect the SGT but I am now trying to find where it is mounted to. How can I find the directory for SGT to save a file to it?

Comment: ...perhaps related [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34718/is-there-a-command-to-see-where-a-disk-is-mounted).

Comment: What do you mean "it does not have any OS currently"? What happened to the default Android? If you've actually removed _everything_ from the tablet, congratulations! Do you have a Windows machine handy?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi it has currently only the Samsung bootloader. My friend tried to update it but it did not work. Yes, I have Windows 8 in virtual machine.

Comment: You should be able to flash with Odin. You might have to wait a while for the full answer, I'm not currently home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you should be able to flash using [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27843397). I'm not sure it works through a VM though, so perhaps you might have better luck with [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/).

Basically, you need to get the appropriate firmware for your device from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/) (signup required). Then, shut down your device and boot it while holding volume down + power. Once the tablet enters download mode, connect it to a PC.

If using Odin, the file you downloaded goes into the PDA box. I'm not too sure about Heimdall, but it looks like the downloaded file goes into the "Heimdall firmware package" box. Then click "Start" in Odin and wait for your device to reboot.

At this point, the tablet *should* boot into Android.

Comment: I've never been able to get Heimdall to work, but Odin definitely should do the  trick.  If you pass through the USB port to the VM it should work (at least, it does using VirtualBox on Ubuntu).